# Video with breakpoints for Keynote presentation

Tags: presentation

I'm trying to show a demo walkthrough of our iPhone app in a Keynote presentation. Ideally, the video would play for a while and then stop at preset break points. Button press resumes the video until the next breaking point.

What's the best way to do this? Do you recommend going about this differently altogether?